# Identify Flowers in an Image and count

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

I have this image which has flowers and my interest is using object detection to Identify this flowers then count them. Here is the image:

[image: Flower petals]

Now I have written an object detection code but it doesn't identify flowers as expected, it counts other objects in the image too. It gives wrong counting on the number of flowers on an image. Here is the code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
from numpy.lib.polynomial import poly

original = cv2.imread("path to image\\obj9.jpeg")

# Convert image in grayscale
gray_im = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.title('Grayscale image')
plt.imshow(gray_im, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)


# Contrast adjusting with gamma correction y = 1.2

gray_correct = np.array(255 * (gray_im / 255) ** 1.2 , dtype='uint8')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.title('Gamma Correction y= 1.2')
plt.imshow(gray_correct, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)

# Contrast adjusting with histogramm equalization
gray_equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray_im)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.title('Histogram equilization')
plt.imshow(gray_correct, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)

# Local adaptative threshold

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_correct, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 255, 19)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.title('Local adapatative Threshold')
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)

# Dilatation et erosion
kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilation,kernel, iterations=1)

# clean all noise after dilatation and erosion
img_erode = cv2.medianBlur(img_erode, 7)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.title('Dilatation + erosion')
plt.imshow(img_erode, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)

# Labeling

ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img_erode)
label_hue = np.uint8(179 * labels / np.max(labels))
blank_ch = 255 * np.ones_like(label_hue)
labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
labeled_img[label_hue == 0] = 0


plt.subplot(222)
plt.title('Objects counted:'+ str(ret-1))
plt.imshow(labeled_img)
print('objects number is:', ret-1)
plt.show()
```

With this code I am able to do a count of objects on the image but it gives a wrong number of flowers. My intention is to separate flowers on an image and do count.I think this might need to include abit of machine learning but any assistance will help. Thank you

Comment: You mean counting the flowers or the petals of a flower? If it is the latter, then it would be almost impossible given those kinds of images.

Comment: @Vishnudev sorry its counting the flowers, let me rectify